# Elixir function does not return expected result

Tags: elixir

This is my code which should sum all numbers between 0 and "number" if it is either multiply of 3 or 5, but always return 0

```
defmodule Challenge do
  def solution(number) do 
    result = 0
    for i <- 0..number-1 do
      if rem(i, 5) == 0 || rem(i, 3) == 0 do
        result = result + i
      end
    end
    result
  end
end
```

This is test:

```
defmodule TestSolution do
  use ExUnit.Case
  import Challenge, only: [solution: 1]

  def test_solution(n, expected) do
    assert solution(n) == expected
  end
  
  test "basic tests" do
    test_solution 10, 23
  end
end
```

Comment: This is because of immutability and scoping. When you do `result = result + i` you're not updating the variable you declared above, but instead just defining another `result` variable which equals `0 + i` inside the scope of your `for` block. So, as soon as you leave that scope it goes away. You're looking for something like [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#reduce/3). The first example in the documentation shows adding all values in a list, you need that same thing but with your conditions.

Comment: Also, `for` in Elixir creates a list based on some inputs, so, that block is producing a list that is not being assigned to anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Elixir, variables are immutable, so you can't really change result variable as in your example, it stays within `for do` code block. Your example would work fine in a OOPS language but Elixir being functional you need to change approach a bit. Elixir provides an [Enum](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) module to iterate through a list in much more effective way and your solution can easily be replaced with Enum module.

```
 defmodule Challenge do
  def solution(number) do 
    0..number-1
    |> Enum.filter(fn x -> rem(x, 5) == 0 || rem(x, 3) == 0 end)
    |> Enum.sum()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s sometimes better (and almost always faster) to use the native and idiomatic way to enumerate the enumerable, filtering and transforming the result on the fly. Here is the recursive solution:

```elixir
defmodule Challenge do
  def solution(number) do 
    add(0, number)
  end

  defp add(i, max, acc \\ 0)
  defp add(max, max, acc), do: acc
  defp add(i, max, acc) when rem(i, 3) == 0,
    do: add(i + 1, max, acc + i)
  defp add(i, max, acc) when rem(i, 5) == 0,
    do: add(i + 1, max, acc + i)
  defp add(i, max, acc), do: add(i + 1, max, acc)
end
```